# how to solve Validation failed for classes [*] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-validator

my entity class

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1,message = "is required")
@LinkExists
private String link;
```

my annotation class LinkExists

```
String message() default "Invalid Link";

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
```

annotation constraint class

```
private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;
private static final String youtubePattern = "^(http(s)?:\\/\\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\\.com)?\\/.+";

@Override
public boolean isValid(final String link, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    
    pattern = Pattern.compile(youtubePattern);
    if (link == null) {
        return false;
    }
    matcher = pattern.matcher(link);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

i am using spring boot with custom annotaions
but whenever i enter bad input it crashes and shows following log in console

```
Validation failed for classes [com.modern.school.entity.Video] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Invalid Link', propertyPath=link, rootBeanClass=class com.modern.school.entity.Video, messageTemplate='Invalid Link'}
]
```

@LinkExists is my custom annotation
how to i fix this . please help

Comment: to fixe you have to enter a valid link that respect your regex, how is your annotation use ?

Comment: @LinkExists is my annotation

Answer (score 0):

1. you are trying to validate a link (which you suppose to be valid) and you get that error ?

try to remove extra \ on the first and last groupe of your pattern

this

```
^(http(s)?:\\/\\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\\.com)?\\/.+
```

to

```
^(http(s)?:\/\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\.com)?\/.+
```

tested with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sssssssss

2. I noticed that in your validation you are checking null, then this `@NotNull` is useless (keep one)
3. i think you have to change your name from **LinkExists** to something like **validYoutubeLink**, because valid does not mean the video exists